# Kafka async Commit Offset Replication

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We occasionally suffer from high latency between the replica leader and the rest of the ISR nodes which lead to the consumer getting the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Commit offsets failed with retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
```

I can increase the `offsets.commit.timeout.ms` but I don't want to as it may lead to additional side effects.
But on broader view,I don't want the broker to wait syncing the commit offset on all the other replicas, rather commit locally and async update the rest.
Going over the broker configuration I found `offsets.commit.required.acks` which looks to configure exactly that, BUT the doc also cryptically states: `the default (-1) should not be overridden`.

Why? I even tried going over the broker source code but found little additional information.

Any idea why this isn't recommended? is there a different way of achieving the same result?

Comment: If this problem is transient, you could probably increase 'request.timeout.ms'  .

Comment: we are running into the exact same issue on Kafka 2.1.1... Any success in troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to actually retry committing the offsets.

Let your consumer commit the offsets asynchronously and implement a retry mechanism. However, retrying an asynchronous commit could lead to the case that you commit a smaller offset after committing a larger offset which should be avoided by all means.

In the book "Kafka - The Definitive Guide", there is a hint on how to mitigate this problem:

> Retrying Async Commits: A simple pattern to get commit order right for asynchronous retries is to use a monotonically increasing sequence number. Increase the sequence number every time you commit and add the sequence number at the time of the commit to the commitAsync callback. When you’re getting ready to send a retry, check if the commit sequence number the callback got is equal to the instance variable; if it is, there was no newer commit and it is safe to retry. If the instance sequence number is higher, don’t retry because a newer commit was already sent.

As an example, you can see an implementation of this idea in Scala below:

```scala
import java.util._
import java.time.Duration
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, ConsumerRecord, KafkaConsumer, OffsetAndMetadata, OffsetCommitCallback}
import org.apache.kafka.common.{KafkaException, TopicPartition}
import collection.JavaConverters._

object AsyncCommitWithCallback extends App {

  // define topic
  val topic = "myOutputTopic"

  // set properties
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "AsyncCommitter5")
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  // [set more properties...]
  

  // create KafkaConsumer and subscribe
  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
  consumer.subscribe(List(topic).asJavaCollection)

  // initialize global counter
  val atomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)

  // consume message
  try {
    while(true) {
      val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1)).asScala

      if(records.nonEmpty) {
        for (data <- records) {
          // do something with the records
        }
        consumer.commitAsync(new KeepOrderAsyncCommit)
      }

    }
  } catch {
    case ex: KafkaException => ex.printStackTrace()
  } finally {
    consumer.commitSync()
    consumer.close()
  }


  class KeepOrderAsyncCommit extends OffsetCommitCallback {
    // keeping position of this callback instance
    val position = atomicLong.incrementAndGet()

    override def onComplete(offsets: util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata], exception: Exception): Unit = {
      // retrying only if no other commit incremented the global counter
      if(exception != null){
        if(position == atomicLong.get) {
          consumer.commitAsync(this)
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```